# Does Nssortdescriptor convert contents of the array to integer after sorting?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray, nssortdescriptor

Given the below code, in the first iteration the logs are displayed normally. For the second iteration the app crashes with the following error message:

```
019-11-07 09:54:08.156277+0100 xxxion[520:202084] iconNumberString : 1026
2019-11-07 09:54:12.160849+0100 xxxtion[520:202084] [self.iconNumbers lastObject]) : 1026
2019-11-07 09:54:24.598805+0100 xxxion[520:202084] -[__NSSingleObjectArrayI addObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2824a3fd0
(lldb)
```

The nssortdescriptor used:

```
        NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"intValue" ascending:YES];
```

To solve this issue:
1-as I thought that the nssordescriptor converts the contents of the array to integer as the specified key specifies in the nssortdescriptor, the following log added:
            NSLog(@"[self.iconNumbers lastObject]) : %i", [self.iconNumbers lastObject]);
            to check if the values were converted to integer or not

the question is:
1-does nssortdescriptopn converts the contents of the NSArray to integer as the nssordescriptor specifies -initWithKey:@"intValue"-?

2-for this line_

```
 self.iconNumbers = (NSMutableArray *)[self.iconNumbers    
 sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];
```

why the changes should not have been applied directly on -self.iconnumbers-?? why I have to assign the results of the RightHandSide to the same -self.iconnumber- again??

**code**:

```
For loop 
 [self.iconNumbers addObject:iconNumberString];
         self.iconNumbers = (NSMutableArray *)[self.iconNumbers sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];
        NSLog(@"iconNumberString : %@", iconNumberString);
        NSLog(@"[self.iconNumbers lastObject]) : %@", [self.iconNumbers lastObject]);

        NSLog(@"[self.iconNumbers lastObject]) : %i", [self.iconNumbers lastObject]);//added for testing after received the crash
End of loop
```

Comment: `sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:` returns a NSArray. Casting, ie doing `(NSMutableArray *)something` isn't magic. It won't transform the `NSArray` into a `NSMutableArray`. It just tells the compiler, don't be afraid, I'm telling you it's a `NSMutableArray`, trust me (and you're wrong). Either, use `sortUsingDescriptors:` directly, or replace `(NSMutableArray *)` with `[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:`

Answer (score 1):

`sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:` returns a `NSArray`. It's not applying on itself, it's applying on a "copy" and returning the sorted copy.

Casting, ie doing `(NSMutableArray *)something` isn't magic. It won't transform the `NSArray` into a `NSMutableArray`. It just tells the compiler, don't be afraid, I'm telling you it's a `NSMutableArray`, treat it as such for the next time, trust me (and you're wrong).

Either, use `sortUsingDescriptors:` directly, or replace `(NSMutableArray *)` with `[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:`

```
For loop 
    [self.iconNumbers addObject:iconNumberString];
    self.iconNumbers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[self.iconNumbers sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]]];
End of loop
```

or

```
For loop 
    [self.iconNumbers addObject:iconNumberString];
    [self.iconNumbers sortUsingDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];
End of loop
```

For the rest:

It will use the sortDescriptor as a "conversion" for the sort, but it won't replace the value with the conversion. 
Imagine, you have an array of NSDictionary looking like this: `@{@"key1": @"Hello", @"key2": @"Hi"}`, setting the descriptor won't replace each dictionary with the value of key1 (Hello).

Finally, you can only have a `NSObject` in a `NS(Mutable)Array`, no primitive. It'd be then, at the max, a `NSNumber` encapsulating a `Int`.